# "La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor" al intentar ejecutar código

Tags: sql

```sql
SELECT Nombre,Apellido,Documento
FROM Staff
WHERE Nombre=(SELECT Nombre FROM Asignaturas WHERE Nombre LIKE ('%UX%'))
```

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 105
> La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza como expresión.

Comment: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 105
La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza como expresión.

Comment: El error es claro. La subconsulta devuelve más de un valor y eso no es permitido cuando se está usando con operadores de comparación. Debes cambiar la consulta para que siempre devuelva un solo valor.

Comment: Como te han dicho, el error es claro. O cambiás la subconsulta para que te devuelva un solo valor, o usás `IN` o `EXISTS`.

Comment: Por cierto... [En este mismo sitio hay preguntas similares](/search?q=La+subconsulta+ha+devuelto+más+de+un+valor) (asumiendo que te referías a sql-server, ya que no lo mencionaste en las etiquetas). No olvides que preguntar debe ser tu _último recurso_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento de [es.so].

Answer (score 0):

Si te devuelve mas de un resultado los operadores de comparacion = != > < >= <= van a fallar. Salvo que uses LIMIT 1 en la subconsulta

```
SELECT Nombre,Apellido,Documento
FROM Staff
WHERE Nombre=(SELECT Nombre FROM Asignaturas WHERE Nombre LIKE ('%UX%')  LIMIT 1)
```

Pueder hacer esto

```
SELECT Nombre,Apellido,Documento
FROM Staff s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM Asignaturas a 
              WHERE a.Nombre LIKE ('%UX%') 
              AND a.Nombre = s.Nombre)
```

O puedes hacer

```
SELECT Nombre,Apellido,Documento
FROM Staff
WHERE Nombre IN (SELECT Nombre FROM Asignaturas WHERE Nombre LIKE ('%UX%'))
```

Tambien por la negativa con NOT EXISTS y NOT IN

Comment: Tuve que editar la respuesta porque la sintaxis de `EXISTS()` estaba incorrecta. También es importante hacer notar que en SQL Server no existe LIMIT, sino TOP (El mensaje de error tiene el formato de SQL Server). Pero más importante es saber que el resultado puede cambiar al regresar un solo valor sin ningún orden asignado.